# Styling an element that is passed into a variable in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm not sure what this is called but I created a variable called test and I set that equal to an element.

`var test = <Button className="testButton" />`

Then in my return, I use my test variable like this:

```
render () {
var test = <Button className="testButton" />
  return{
    {test}
  }
}
```

I've tried to style the button by applying a className but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That button is coming from Material-UI or from what?

It does have connection with Materia-UI somehow. I'm almost sure that the Button gets the class `testButton` and has these styles connected with it. But Button in Material-UI gets styles from inline-styles thanks to MUI-Theme.

Acording to Material-UI website

> All Material-UI components have their styles defined inline.

So basically if your class has styles that aren't `!important` - they will be simply ignored and the inline ones will be taken anyway. There are actually few solutions to that:

- change mui-theme
- override inline-styles
- add to class styles `!important` if you want to override something

Comment: im not sure if it would make a difference, but yes i am using material ui

Comment: It does. I'm almost sure that the Button gets class testButton and has these styles connected with it. But Button in Material-UI gets styles from inline-styles thanks to MUI-Theme. If you really want to change the styles in these buttons, use !important in styles connected to that class.

Or better, try to change themes (or add inline styles).